# How can I achieve a list which has features like autocomplete and search in Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart, user-interface

I want to achieve this type of UI in Flutter -

[image: First]

[image: Second]

[image]

I tried `Autocomplete` Class, but I don't know how to get this list type of UI using it. Then I though about using a textfield, and everytime when it's value changes, I use ListView.builder() and do like -
`list[index].contains(textEditingcontroller.text.toLowerCase())` to built this list below. So can someone suggest me an optimal/better approach on how to get this UI.

Comment: You should check this library https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_typeahead

Comment: @esentis I did, but the bottom shert, in which the search is showing is not similar to the required UI. I need exactly similar type of UI in my app, as shown in the images above.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this native flutter widgets to achieve this [SearchDelegate](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/SearchDelegate-class.html) and another is [AutoComplete](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Autocomplete-class.html). looking from your use case search delegate might be the one.